# how to validate and post entire Viewdata and Hiddenfield data to Actionmethod

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

im very new to mvc 4,
Hi assume there are 6 controls in form in that 2 controls are dropdown,remain is textbox.
how can we assign dropdownlist seletected text to hidden field, and how to pass entire form data to the Controlers action method.

help dropdown validation also while sending the form data.

pls links /code/ suggestion.

regards
raja

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit on what the  requirement is?

Answer (score 0):

go through the tutorials here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3 for MVC3 and here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4 for MVC4